# Using parfor on submatrix in matlab

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, matlab

I have a piece of code that divides a image matrix `img` into small piece and work on them parallel. But Matlab says `parfor` loop cannot be used, because the way `outC{i,j}` is indexed. How do I fix this?

The sub matrices are of different size. If `img=[4x7]`, then

```
C=[3x3 3x3 3x1;
   1x3 1x3 1x1]
```

On a side note, I'm not sure if using cell array is a good idea here. If not, feel free to give suggestion on how to divide up the `img` as well.

```
C=mat2cell(img, rowSplit, colSplit);
[rowc,colc]=size(C);
outC=cell(rowc,colc);
parfor i=1:rowc
    for j=1:colc
       outC{i,j}=doWork(C{i,j}); 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use linear indexing for both the input and output.

First I make a pretend input of your shape, and a simple `doWork` function:

```
>> C= {rand(3) rand(3) rand(3,1); rand(1,3) rand(1,3) rand(1)};
>> C
C = 
    [3x3 double]    [3x3 double]    [3x1 double]
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [    0.3922]
>> doWork = @(x)2*x;
```

Then use linear indexing:

```
>> outC=cell(size(C));
>> parfor ci=1:numel(C)
     outC{ci} = doWork(C{ci});
   end
```

A quick check that it's worked:

```
>> outC{2,1}./C{2,1}
ans =
     2     2     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many answers here that will help in using a `parfor` block to do what you need, I would think that an even better solution might be to use an [spmd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/brukbno-1.html) block instead.

Rather than splitting your image up into smaller portions within a cell array, consider instead converting it into a [distributed array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/br9_n7w-1.html), perhaps distributing in the same portions as you're currently doing. Within the `spmd` block, you can execute your `doWork` function, and it will be applied to whatever portion of the (co-)distributed array is present on that worker. Finally you can assemble the results and [gather](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/gather.html) them back to the client.

I find `spmd` more complex to grasp than `parfor`, but it's very powerful once you've got the idea of it; and I would think this example might be very conveniently expressed in that form.

Comment: Could you give an example of code? I have an image I want to apply a filter on it. For instance, a filter of radius 5. What would be the best way to parllelize it? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just build a vector of outputs, and use `reshape` afterwards to make it into a matrix.

Comment: Could you show how this can be done? The sub matrices are of different size, e.g. img=[4x7] becomes C=[3x3 3x3 3x1;1x3 1x3 1x1].

Comment: @Usavich: I meant with the cell array.  Does it work if you wrote `outC{i + j*colc} = ...` and then called `reshape`?